# PHP - preg_match alternative

Tags: php, regex

I'm using `preg_match()` in PHP to detect queries related to weather. However, it detects a match for the string if it is inside another string. For example, "mayweather" will evaluate to true.

```
<?php
    $q = "floyd mayweather";
    if(preg_match('(weather|forecast|temperature)', $q) === 1) {
        echo "match";
    }
?>
```

What should I use instead of preg match? I only want it to detect the words "weather", "forecast", and "temperature", but NOT "mayweather", which is a string inside a string.

Comment: See [`\b word boundary`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex, exactly what I needed! If you post an answer with it I'll give you credit for the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [\b word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) tag to indicate that you want to match full words only. Something like this:

```
preg_match('/\b(weather|forecast|temperature)\b/i', $q)
```